# No copy method in WebHDFS

Tags: webhdfs

WebHDFS provides hooks for "rename", "delete" and other basic file manipulations. but here is no API hook for copy.  Would someone mind explaining it or any good workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using webhdfs you can :
a. Open and read a file.
b. Create and write to file
Using operation a and b you can emulate copy?
If there is a more efficient way I would like to know too:-)